# How to get working query from MySQL 5.5 to work in MySQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-order-by, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.7

I have spent many, many hours trying to figure this out. So my query is giving different result on different mysql versions.causes my problem. So far I have figured out that since MySQL 5.6 order by in subqueries are not recognized. And that seems to be the reason of wrong results in 5.7.

I guess I should do that whole end starting from "AND EXISTS" in some different way but I have no clue how.

I have tested this with the same exact database on 3 different servers. One with 5.5 (works) and two with 5.7 (not).

My query: Works: 5.5, Doesn't work: 5.6(?), 5.7

```
SELECT
Sum(P) as games 
FROM(SELECT gameday, league, home, season, id, 1 P
FROM games
UNION ALL
SELECT gameday, league, away, season, id, 1
FROM games) as tot, clubs c WHERE tot.home=c.id AND c.id=1 AND
tot.league<=2 AND tot.season=2010 
AND EXISTS
(select if(e.event<10,1,0) as first from 
(select * from events 
where event<=2 or event=9 or event=10 or event=11 or event=13 
order by event_time asc) as e 
where e.game=tot.id group by e.game having first>0)
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

edit:

Event can be 1,2,9,10,11 or 13

I want to count games where first event is <10. First event of the game is determined by the event_time.

Does this make any sense?

edit2:

Columns in events-table

```
- id (primary, auto_increment)
- game
- player
- event
- event_time
```

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" can you be more specific? Can you explain what you're trying to do? You are misusing MySQL's nonstandard extension to `GROUP BY`.  That means the MySQL server is free to choose the  `e.event` value appearing in your `if(e.event<10,1,0)` clause in an unpredictable way. It looks like the query planner changed between versions. It's a miracle you ever got predictable results.  Read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: That accursed extension claims another victim.  Grumble.

Comment: Thank you @OllieJones for taking the time. I know I am using group by incorrectly but as I said this works like I want it to work in 5.5. But now I am looking some another way of doing this without misusing group by. I edited my question about what I'm trying to achieve here. If you could look at it and point me to some direction would be awesome :)

Comment: It was (unfortunately)  nothing but random luck that your query worked correctly in any given version of MySQL.

Comment: I understand. Do you have any idea how to do this in another way and get the desired results?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the columns in your `events` table. Does it have an autoincrementing `id` column?

Comment: Edited and yes it does.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working myself eventually. Here is what I am using now

```
SELECT
Sum(P) as games 
FROM(SELECT gameday, league, home, season, id, 1 P 
FROM games
UNION ALL
SELECT gameday, league, away, season, id, 1
FROM games) as tot, clubs c WHERE tot.home=c.id AND c.id=1 AND
tot.league<=2 AND tot.season=2010 
AND EXISTS
(select if(e.event<10,1,0) as first from 
(select game, min(event_time), 
substring_index(group_concat(event order by event_time), ',', 1) as event 
from events 
where event<=2 or event=9 or event=10 or event=11 or event=13 
group by game) as e 
where e.game=tot.id having first>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first objective is to locate the first qualified event from each game. "Qualified" means having one of the `event` values you mentioned. There's a nice trick here. The event with the lowest-numbered `id` for each game is the first event.

So that gets you this. It's a list of the ids / game for the first qualified event.

```
             SELECT MIN(id) id, game
               FROM events
              WHERE event < 2
                 OR event IN (9,10,11,13)
              GROUP BY game
```

Next you need the actual first event for each game, not just its id.

```
      SELECT a.event, a.game
        FROM event a
        JOIN (
               SELECT MIN(id) id, game
                 FROM events
                GROUP BY game
             ) b ON a.id = b.id
       WHERE a.event < 10
```

This yields an event / game list of the first event of each game, but it excludes the games where the first event value is >= 10.

Next, you've correctly come up with a union list of the home and away games. This query generates a row for each game

```
       SELECT tot.p
         FROM (
               SELECT gameday, league, home, season, id, 1 AS p FROM games
                UNION ALL
               SELECT gameday, league, away, season, id, 1 AS p FROM games
              ) tot
         JOIN clubs c ON tot.home = c.id
        WHERE tot.league <= 2
          AND tot.season >= 2010
          AND c.id = 1
```

Finally, join your selection of games with the first event < 10, and add up the result.

```
SELECT SUM(tot.p) gamecount
  FROM (
        SELECT gameday, league, home, season, id, 1 AS p FROM games
         UNION ALL
        SELECT gameday, league, away, season, id, 1 AS p FROM games
       ) tot
  JOIN clubs c ON tot.home = c.id
  JOIN (
          SELECT a.event, a.game
            FROM event a
            JOIN (
                   SELECT MIN(id) id, game
                     FROM events
                    GROUP BY game
                 ) b ON a.id = b.id
           WHERE a.event < 10
       ) eligible ON eligible.game = tot.id
 WHERE tot.league <= 2
   AND tot.season >= 2010
   AND c.id = 1
```

My point in writing this is to show the "S" -- structured -- in SQL. Building your query starting with simple building blocks gets you two things.

1. a correct answer
2. a way to debug by running the subqueries, making sure they work, and then incorporating them in the bigger query.

Comment: Thank you, very nice answer. But in my case this wouldn't produce the correct answer. Because in the events-table the first event of the game doesn't always have the lowest id. But anyway, thank you for explaining how it would be best to build a query. I appreciate it!